# A Kotlin service with request queue

Tags: kotlin, architecture, future, deferred, kotlin-coroutines

I would like to design an a service with the following API:

`suspend fun getUsers(request: Request): List<User>`

Under the hood I would send a request to the server (doesn't matter how, but lets say it's a reactive `WebClient`), but here's a trick: I can only send requests as often as every 500 ms, otherwise I will get an error.

Could someone recommend me how I could implement it such way that when I call `getUsers` from a coroutine it suspends, the unit of work is being added to some queue of the service that has this method, then implemented at some point in time and returned the result?

I assume I can use some `ReceiveChannel` as a queue, have a `for` loop for its elements with a `delay` inside, but I'm a bit lost where to put this logic. Should this be like a background method that will run forever and gets called by `getUsers`? Probably the `close` method will never be called, so this method can also be suspended, but how do I pass the value back from this infinite running method to `getUsers` that needs the results?

**EDIT**

At the moment I'm thinking of a solution like this:

```
private const val REQUEST_INTERVAL = 500

@Service
class DelayedRequestSenderImpl<T> : DelayedRequestSender<T> {
    private var lastRequestTime: LocalDateTime = LocalDateTime.now()
    private val requestChannel: Channel<Deferred<T>> = Channel()

    override suspend fun requestAsync(block: () -> T): Deferred<T> {
        val deferred = GlobalScope.async(start = CoroutineStart.LAZY) { block() }
        requestChannel.send(deferred)
        return deferred
    }

    @PostConstruct
    private fun startRequestProcessing() = GlobalScope.launch {
        for (request in requestChannel) {
            val now = LocalDateTime.now()
            val diff = ChronoUnit.MILLIS.between(lastRequestTime, now)
            if (diff < REQUEST_INTERVAL) {
                delay(REQUEST_INTERVAL - diff)
                lastRequestTime = now
            }
            request.start()
        }
    }
}
```

The problem I see here is that I have to generify the class to make the `requestChannel` generic, since the result of request may be anything. But this means that each instance of `DelayedRequestSender` will be tied to a particular type. Any advice on how to avoid this?

**EDIT 2**

Here's a refined version. The only possible flow that I see at the moment is that we have to make `@PostConstruct` method public in order to write any tests if we want or use reflection.

The idea was to not use `GlobalScope` and also have a separate `Job` for the processing method. Is this a fine approach?

```
interface DelayingSupplier {
    suspend fun <T> supply(block: () -> T): T
}

@Service
class DelayingSupplierImpl(@Value("\${vk.request.interval}") private val interval: Int) : DelayingSupplier {
    private var lastRequestTime: LocalDateTime = LocalDateTime.now()
    private val requestChannel: Channel<Deferred<*>> = Channel()
    private val coroutineScope = CoroutineScope(EmptyCoroutineContext)

    override suspend fun <T> supply(block: () -> T): T {
        val deferred = coroutineScope.async(start = CoroutineStart.LAZY) { block() }
        requestChannel.send(deferred)
        return deferred.await()
    }

    @PostConstruct
    fun startProcessing() = coroutineScope.launch(context = Job(coroutineScope.coroutineContext[Job])) {
        for (request in requestChannel) {
            val now = LocalDateTime.now()
            val diff = ChronoUnit.MILLIS.between(lastRequestTime, now)
            if (diff < interval) {
                delay(interval - diff)
            }
            lastRequestTime = LocalDateTime.now()
            request.start()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: could not help you with the coroutines but some ideas comes to my mind. Is it allowed to call the server from your client every 500ms? or from each instance of your request sender? what about having one singleton request sender (if the first situation is the case) which does not use generics, instead use raw strings .. and than have a nother - higher level service - which parse the data into objects and those could be several instances ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So this is the final implementation I came up with. Note the `SupevisorJob` as we don't want the processing to stop if one of requests fails, which is totally possible and fine (in my case at least).

Also, the option suggested by @Laurence might be better, but I decided to not use actors for now due to API being marked as obsolete.

```
@Service
class DelayingRequestSenderImpl(@Value("\${vk.request.interval}") private val interval: Int) : DelayingRequestSender {
    private var lastRequestTime: LocalDateTime = LocalDateTime.now()
    private val requestChannel: Channel<Deferred<*>> = Channel()
    //SupervisorJob is used because we want to have continuous processing of requestChannel
    //even if one of the requests fails
    private val coroutineScope = CoroutineScope(SupervisorJob())

    override suspend fun <T> request(block: () -> T): T {
        val deferred = coroutineScope.async(start = CoroutineStart.LAZY) { block() }
        requestChannel.send(deferred)
        return deferred.await()
    }

    @PostConstruct
    fun startProcessing() = coroutineScope.launch {
        for (request in requestChannel) {
            val now = LocalDateTime.now()
            val diff = ChronoUnit.MILLIS.between(lastRequestTime, now)
            if (diff < interval) {
                delay(interval - diff)
            }
            lastRequestTime = LocalDateTime.now()
            request.start()
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend:

- pushing your generics down to the function level
- using an actor instead of your coroutine implementation (but possibly you prefer this).

Either way, this solution should let you use a single instance of your queue to handle the delay of all requests regardless of return type. (Apologies, I renamed some things to help my own conceptualization, hopefully this still makes sense):

```
private const val REQUEST_INTERVAL = 500

interface DelayedRequestHandler {

    suspend fun <T> handleWithDelay(block: () -> T): T

}

class DelayedRequestHandlerImpl(requestInterval: Int = REQUEST_INTERVAL) : DelayedRequestHandler, CoroutineScope {
    private val job = Job()
    override val coroutineContext = Dispatchers.Unconfined + job
    private val delayedHandlerActor = delayedRequestHandlerActor(requestInterval)

    override suspend fun <T> handleWithDelay(block: () -> T): T {
        val result = CompletableDeferred<T>()
        delayedHandlerActor.send(DelayedHandlerMsg(result, block))
        return result.await()
    }
}

private data class DelayedHandlerMsg<RESULT>(val result: CompletableDeferred<RESULT>, val block: () -> RESULT)

private fun CoroutineScope.delayedRequestHandlerActor(requestInterval: Int) = actor<DelayedHandlerMsg<*>>() {
    var lastRequestTime: LocalDateTime = LocalDateTime.now()
    for (message in channel) {
        try {
            println("got a message processing")
            val now = LocalDateTime.now()
            val diff = ChronoUnit.MILLIS.between(lastRequestTime, now)
            if (diff < requestInterval) {
                delay(requestInterval - diff)
            }
            lastRequestTime = LocalDateTime.now()
            @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
            val msgCast = message as DelayedHandlerMsg<Any?>
            val result = msgCast.block()
            println(result)
            msgCast.result.complete(result)
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            message.result.completeExceptionally(e)
        }
    }
}


fun main() = runBlocking {
    val mydelayHandler = DelayedRequestHandlerImpl(2000)
    val jobs = List(10) {
        launch {
            mydelayHandler.handleWithDelay {
                "Result $it"
            }
        }
    }
    jobs.forEach { it.join() }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion! However, `actor` is marked with `@ObsoleteCoroutinesApi`, so I think it's better to try to avoid using it

Comment: @Leonid Bor they are, but the semantics of this is explained here https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/issues/632 there is no alternative for now, but they will be present in the future, and a migration will be available. They are still the correct approach for encapsulating state for thread safety through channel communication.

Comment: I have provided a second attempt at implementing this concept based on your code, but without using actor. Could you please have a look and see if it has any problems that I might be missing?

Comment: @Leonid Bor Looks fine, only issue is that lastRequestTime is not protected by the channel for thread safety and access.

Comment: aren't they processed sequentially? The loop is being run within a single coroutine, so I was thinking the instances of `Deferred` would be started sequentially, same as time being updated

Comment: @Leonid Bor They are, but you could write a function in  that object which has access to that variable without going through the channel

Comment: Not sure I see how that might be possible. The class is final and the property is private, am I missing something? Could you provide an example, please?

Comment: @Leonid Bor So similar to how my actor instantiates that variable in the context of the function, you could initialise it in the body of your launch block.

Comment: Currently someone could come and write code that is not thread safe on that class and access that variable. This is a very minor issue to be clear